# iphonesdk value removing from arrray given exc bad access

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

i had implemented this code, when i try to add objects it works fine but when i try to remove object it gave me exc_bad_access, i try to find out through putting break points but still i cannot get the reason of this. please help me.

**in .h file**

```
BOOL prayValues[1000];
BOOL praiseValues[1000];
IBOutlet UITableView *prayTable;
IBOutlet UITableView *praiseTable;
NSMutableArray *publishingMyPosts;




- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //NSLog(@"sterrrr----%@",str);

    if (tableView == myTableView) {
    NSLog(@"did select in tableview");
    }



    if (jsonRequestChecking==2) {

        UITableViewCell *thisCell1 = [prayTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UITableViewCell *thisCell2 = [praiseTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (tableView == prayTable) {
        NSLog(@"did select in prayTable");      
        prayValues[indexPath.row] = !prayValues[indexPath.row];

        if (prayValues[indexPath.row]) { 
            thisCell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            NSLog(@"this cell1 text %@",thisCell1.textLabel.text);
            str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[publicArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]];

            if (([publishingMyPosts containsObject:str] == NO)){

                [publishingMyPosts addObject:str];
            //  NSLog(@"publishing my post %@",publishingMyPosts);


            }

        } else {
            thisCell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

            [publishingMyPosts  removeObject:str];
            //NSLog(@"publishing my post %@",publishingMyPosts);

        }



        }



    if (tableView == praiseTable) {
        NSLog(@"did select in praiseTable");
        praiseValues[indexPath.row] = !praiseValues[indexPath.row];
        if (praiseValues[indexPath.row]) { 
            str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[privateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]];
            thisCell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            NSLog(@"this cell2 text %@",thisCell2.textLabel.text);

            if (([publishingMyPosts containsObject:str1] == NO)){
                [publishingMyPosts addObject:str1];
            //  NSLog(@"publishing my post %@",publishingMyPosts);


            }

        } else {
            thisCell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            [publishingMyPosts  removeObject:str1];
            //NSLog(@"publishing my post %@",publishingMyPosts);

        }

        }
    }

    NSLog(@"publishing my post %@",publishingMyPosts);

    }
```

Comment: Think it must be to do with your str being autoreleased between calls? Still looking through it.

Comment: are you sure you app is crashing due to removing the obj from array???

Comment: yap. im sure, its given me exc bad access when ever i try to remove object, and its random some time it remove 3 objects and then give me exc bad access and some time while removing 2 object

Comment: NSString * str; NSString * str1; are declared in .h file with property nonatomic and retain and im releasing it no where.

Comment: are you using `[str release]` or [str1 release]` in your code????

Comment: I think that object is not existing in array

Comment: @hitman- if the object is not existing in the array then it has no effect..the method does nothing in that case.. please refer the docs for more

Comment: Can't see anything obvious with the code you've provided. Might be worthwhile turning on NSZombieEnabled to check a little deeper. See: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease

Comment: no iam not using [str release] or [str1 release]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your indexpath.row is look like to be an issue, hope this may work :

```
    if (indexPath.row < [publicArray count] ) {
    str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[publicArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]];
    NSLog(@"str === %@",str);
    }

    if (indexPath.row < [privateArray count] ){ 
    str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[privateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]];
    NSLog(@"str1 === %@",str1);
}
    if (tableView == myTableView) {
    NSLog(@"did select in tableview");
    }



    if (jsonRequestChecking==2) {

        UITableViewCell *thisCell1 = [prayTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UITableViewCell *thisCell2 = [praiseTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (tableView == prayTable) {

        prayValues[indexPath.row] = !prayValues[indexPath.row];
        if (prayValues[indexPath.row]) { 
            thisCell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;


            if (([publishingMyPosts containsObject:str] == NO)){

                [publishingMyPosts addObject:str];

            }

            }

        else {
            thisCell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

            [publishingMyPosts  removeObject:str];
        }   



    }



        if (tableView == praiseTable) {

            praiseValues[indexPath.row] = !praiseValues[indexPath.row];
            if (praiseValues[indexPath.row]) { 
                thisCell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;


                if (([publishingMyPosts containsObject:str1] == NO)){

                    [publishingMyPosts addObject:str1];

                }

            }

            else {
                thisCell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

                [publishingMyPosts  removeObject:str1];
            }   



        }






    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare your str Like this...

NSString *str = [[ NSString StringWithFormat:@"your string "] retain];

or Write your str  @property (nonatomic,retain) and @synthesize, becoz some time String being autoreleased so for that be write retain. I think it helps u.....

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because you're not updating the uitableview by deleting the corresponding row. So the table view tries to load the data you've just removed and crashes. You should call  DeleteRowsAtIndexPaths right after the removeObject or alternatively call reloadData at the end of the function.